# Query matching string tags

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's assume that I have millions of rows in SQL, using PostgreSQL to query.
Each row contains the string `~~~&AA=~~~` or not. 
And out of all rows, I need to get the rows that CONTAINS `AA=`.

Then what would be the best way to query this?

I tried the following but it is extremely slow.

```
SELECT my_column
FROM table
WHERE my_column 
    LIKE '%AA=%'
```

What should I use?

Comment: Can you add a column of 0/1 to check the value every time data changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to figure out a way to make an index or use something else like a search engine.

First have a look at why [LIKE can be slow in postgresl and how to make i faster at use-the-index-luke](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning). Basically it boils down to either using [special index functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-opclass.html) or consider using [Postgresql Fulltext Search Support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html).

Also it wasn't clear from your question if every other row actually contains the contents `~~~&AA=~~~` then why not just `WHERE my_column = '~~~&AA=~~~'`? If that is the case you can easily create a partial index for `~~~&AA=~~~` as Postgresql supports partial indexes.

Comment: I don't think index opclasses are relevant here. As far as I'm aware, they just allow pattern expressions to use indexes when the indexed column has a non-`C` collation specified in the table. That is, in an index definition, I think `text_pattern_ops` is effectively syntactic sugar for `COLLATE "C"`. It's still bound by the standard constraints (i.e. it will only use the index for a constant prefix in an anchored expression), so it's not much help here.

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with `LIKE` expressions, Postgres can only use a `btree` index (the default index type) for characters before the first wildcard. So for something like `my_col LIKE 'ABC%XYZ'`, it can search the index for strings starting with `'ABC'`. When the wildcard is the first character, it can't use an index at all.

As [Adam Gent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215823/postgresql-query-matching-string-tags/24215997#24215997) pointed out, if you want to look for arbitrary substrings, then you'll need additional data structures to support full-text search, which is far from trivial.

But if you're always looking for `'AA='`, and if you're doing it often enough, you can create an index specifically for this query, i.e.

```
CREATE INDEX ON my_table ((my_column LIKE '%AA=%'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is probably the best you can write it for the data you are trying to get.  One thing you can try to speed up the query is to index the column you are searching.  This might not be the best solution if the data type of the field will let you store a very large amount of data. Otherwise, as suggested before, you could set flag in the row for the data you are interested in if it is more of a static text you are looking for.