# SQL : should I insert another column or parse every single row

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, postgresql, text-processing

Assume millions of lines of traffic data in SQL format.
From the column `URL` and for each row of given range, I want to get a substring text that matches the target tag.

For example, from the column `URL`, I have the following texts:

```
Column: `URL`
Row 1: http://www.google.com/abcdeft?&QQ=123&AA=america&YY=111
Row 2: http://www.google.com/abcdeft?&QQ=123&AA=asia&YY=111
Row 3: http://www.google.com/abcdeft?&QQ=123&AA=africa&YY=111
Row 4: http://www.google.com/abcdeft?&QQ=123&AA=south&YY=111
Row 5: http://www.google.com/abcdeft?&QQ=123&AA=south&YY=111
Row 6: http://www.google.com/abcdeft?&QQ=123&AA=&YY=111
Row 7: http://www.google.com/abcdeft?&QQ=123
...
Row 99999999: http://www.google.com/abcdeft?&QQ=123&AA=ddd&YY=111
```

Data keep being loaded with lots of updates. So performance does matter. My goal is to:

1. Identify each row with its unique key-tag `&AA=`. Basically I need to get the string in the tag `&AA=` from every single row. For example, I want `africa` from `~~&AA=africa&~~`. `None` if there is no `&AA=` but still need to read every single row.
2. Identify duplicate rows that contain the same tag in `&AA=`. e.g. row 4 and 5 are duplicates because they have same `AA` tags of `south`.

Question: which would be the best way for future data processing?

**Option 1**. Without `URL` column

- Read every single row in `URL` column
- Parse each row for the tag `&AA=` using `urlparse` library
- Need a separate script to find duplicate rows with the same `AA` tag. e.g. using Python, I need to make a list of all items(all tags) and find the duplicate items in the list.
- Need a separate query to find the rows that contain duplicate tags. e.g. query the rows that contain the duplicate items in the column `URL`
- **Creating separate column specifically for this task seems relatively doable**.

**Option 2**. Insert another new column `AA` for tag `&AA=` and start filling out the new column when updating traffic data.

In this way:

- **No need to** Read the column `URL`
- **No need to** Parse the text in `URL` to get the tag `&AA=`
- **No need to** Find duplicate items from one query
      - **No need to** etrieve rows with duplicate items from another query

In this way, we can easily:

- Get `&AA=` data just selecting the column `AA`
- `SELECT` duplicate rows using `COUNT` function in SQL

Which one would perform better?

Comment: Please provide your bank details so we know where to send you money for the opportunity to write this code. In other words... What have you tried?

Comment: How about normalizing your database?  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: [Is your dataset related to this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24215823/812837)?  Depends on how often you go duplicate-hunting, but you most likely want a separate column (or one or more other possibilities).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can stand the extra space cost of having an additional column then that would be the optimal approach.  If there are a lot of duplicates of AA you might consider putting that in another table and then joining to it for queries.  That would cut down on the space cost and still give you all the flexiblity.  it would make it even easier (faster to query) if you were querying on an ID instead of the textual value of AA.