# SQL : Insert and Update a new column from existing column

Tags: python, mysql, sql, postgresql

[Query matching string tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24215823/query-matching-string-tags)

SQL : Insert and Update a new column from existing column

I want to insert a new column in my PostGRESQL data, parsing from an existing column.

I have a string `http://google.com/sadfasdfsd&AA=mytag&SS=sdfsdf` that is being updated in the column `URL`. Then how could I insert a new column in this database with a name `AAtag`. I will be using Python to parse the string. Please help me to write the queries for the following tasks:

---

Query 1. Insert a new column `AAtag` to this table.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD AAtag varchar
```

Is it correct? `AAtag` needs to be quoted or not?

---

Query 2. After I run the parsing script from the column `URL` (let's say I have the list of tags in Pyton list), I want to fill out the column `AAtag`.

```
UPDATE table_name
SET AAtag='{0!f}'
WHERE URL='{0!s}';
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query 1: no, AATag doesn't need to be quoted.  However, if it isn't quoted it will be coerced to lower case.  Also, quoting uses double quotes for names as opposed to single quotes for literals.  So, if you didn't quote the statement you would see:

```
create table table_name (URL text);
alter table table_name add AATag varchar;

nsp=# \d table_name
       Table "public.table_name"
 Column |       Type        | Modifiers
--------+-------------------+-----------
 url    | text              |
 aatag  | character varying |
```

Query 2:

```
nsp=# update table_name set AATag = '{0!f}' where URL = '{0!s}';
UPDATE 0 (mine doesnt have any data in it)
```

your example will work for the same reason, the columns are unquoted so will be lower case.  If you really want everything mixed case you would:

```
create table table_name ("URL" text);
alter table table_name add "AATag" varchar;

nsp=# \d table_name
       Table "public.table_name"
 Column |       Type        | Modifiers
--------+-------------------+-----------
 URL    | text              |
 AATag  | character varying |

nsp=# update table_name set "AATag" = '{0!f}' where "URL" = '{0!s}';
UPDATE 0
```

I think I misread this question.  Are you asking how to write a query in sql to change the structure of your database, or how do you write a query in python? The latter is a different subject. Basically, you would:

```
import psycopg2
import psycopg2.extras
pg_conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=dbname host=localhost user=postgres")
pg_cur = pg_conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor)
pg_cur.execute('whatever')
pg_conn.commit()
```

where "whatever" would be the statement you want to execute.  You can prepare statements, provide arguments, etc.. You will need to look at psycopg2 for details.  So, to add the column from python:

```
pg_cur.execute('alter table table_name add "AATag" varchar')
```

of course you need the package installed. on unix that would be:

```
pip install psycopg2
```

but, other operating systems vary.